# How to place Relative layout at bottom of screen(or linear layout).?

Tags: android

I have following in xml

I wanna put the second linear layout at the bottom of the screen.
How will i do?
I have set the property of second Relative layout to bottom but still not showing at bottom..

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">    
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**
Thanx in advance

Comment: I wanna put the second relative layout at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Layout you want at the bottom should have:
`android:gravity = "bottom"`
and its parent should have:
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: I set the both above property Still layout is not at bottom of the screen

Comment: @Sandy Is the parent layout the 'root' layout, i.e. it completely fills the screen? The child layout should also have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Posting your code would help :-)

Comment: Yaa parent layout completely fill the screen.Child have android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Can you post your xml in your question so we can see? Click the `edit` button below the question and paste it in.

Comment: My xml is same as above..I am unable to find out the mistake.Can you please tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: Ah. Have a read [about android:layout_gravity vs android:gravity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

Comment: I am using android:layout_gravity="bottom" which is used for layout so what is wrong?

Answer (score 20):

I was searching for this a while too. My just found solution is to use the property:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

instead of your existing `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

This unfortunately with my layout only works when having an additional **`RelativeLayout` as root layout** and the rest added to it. Maybe this is not always the case, but with having a  `LinearLayout` (even when told to use `fill_parent`) it only used the height all added elements needed and put my footer at the bottom of those.

I came to this solution, looking at this related question: [How do I achieve the following result using RelativeLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555868/how-do-i-achieve-the-following-result-using-relativelayout)

EDIT here because format in answer comment got lost:
Do you mean you can't re-write it or that it didn't work?

I had a vertical LinearLayout too and my new xml structure looks (without the layout size params etc.) sth. like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout01">   
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout02" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you already tried rewriting your xml in the way of my newer example? If it's not working maybe you can give more details on your wanted layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Linearlayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orinationtation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout  android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:weight="1">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:weight="1"
>   
</RelativeLayout>



</Linearlayout >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put a View before your last layout with weight 1, and it will put it to bottom. Like this:

```
    <View android:id="@+id/emptySpace"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#ffb3e5fc"
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerPoint" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/centerPoint"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerPoint" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[It produces something that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XOYz.png)

Answer (score 0):

For my it's work.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/fab_inout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dsfsdfasdf df" />

</RelativeLayout>
```